# How to enable pipelining in MailKit

Tags: c#, windows-services, mailkit

Can anyone suggest me, how we can enable pipelining on MailKit's SMTP client in C#? or what is default value?

Thanks,
Kundan Rai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, if the SMTP server supports the PIPELINING extension ,then MailKit will take advantage of it.

No need for you to do anything.